# Communicating between spark applications

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, airflow

So as the title says I want to communicate between spark applications, which basically means that I have 1 program that generates its output to stdout, and I want to pass the result to another spark application as input.

I will now present the problem and the solutions we thought of in our team:

We are working with CDH 5.1x, using HDFS as our database.
Our data is stored in the following way: One directory is called "staged" for the data in a stream process which is alot of small files, and one directory is called "success" for the "production" data, which is the same data aggregated to one (or many) bigger files.
The data is stored in the following paths:

```
/basePath/staged/{sensor_name}/Y/M/D/H

/basePath/success/{sensor_name}/Y/M/D/H
```

Also, We are using hive partitions over HDFS to mask our hdfs structure to our clients.

We have 3 products, each of them has a different part on the process of moving the data from the "staged" directory to the "success" directory:

1. Aggregation - takes the data from the "staged" directory and unites it to one (or many) files.
2. HivePartitioner - add/remove hive partitions according to the output of Aggregation.
3. Janitor - deletes directories according to an output from aggregation.

The pipeline is: Aggregation -> HivePartitioner -> Janitor.

We are using Airflow to schedule our pipelines with dags.

So, now my problem is how to communicate between the products.
Aggregation should print the results to stdout, the HivePartitioner and the Janitor should receive the result as input.

Here is what we have tried/thought of:

**Option 1:**
Make a dag in airflow which reads the stdout of the Aggregation and transfer the data using xcom (airflow's way of communicating between tasks). This is a good idea, but the problem is, airflow is already proccessing the stdout for it's logs, so I don't have access to the output.

**Option 2:**
Make the following Dag in airflow: Aggregation -> GetYarnLog -> HivePartitioner -> Janitor.

Aggregation will print its output to stdout, which is written to a log file in the cluster and is accessible via the yarn api. Extract the log, process the output and send it to the HivePArtitioner and Janitor.

That's all we thought of without getting into running seperate processes and basically making our own airflow.

I would like your thoughts about our options, and If you guys know a better way of achieving communication between spark applications.
An important thing is, all 3 products must stand alone and not be dependent on the others (decoupling), also the input for each application should be passed into the main method.

Thanks.